# Taking single screenshot instead of whole video

Tags: java, android, screenshot, accessibilityservice, android-mediaprojection

I am using the MediaProjection API to record a short video of whatever is happening on screen, save the video to file, and then I retrieve screenshots by iterating on the frames.

Instead of doing this, is it possible to take directly a screenshot?
I was thinking maybe to take a screenshot with AccessibilityService but that would require a min API level 28: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#GLOBAL_ACTION_TAKE_SCREENSHOT

Comment: "is it possible to take directly a screenshot?" -- you can do that through the media projection APIs too. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/MediaProjection/andshooter).

Comment: @CommonsWare what exactly does `ImageTransmogrifier`?

Comment: When an image arrives from the media projection APIs, `ImageTransmogrifier` goes through the annoying process of converting it into a PNG. That sample is covered in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-8.7-CC.pdf), in the "The Media Projection APIs", starting on page 3157.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! I've noticed that the quality and the size (3.30 Mb against 1.20 Mb) of the screenshot it's not the same as the one taken by `/system/bin/screencap -p`. How can I improve it? I am asking because in your code it's already set to 100 the quality: 

            `cropped.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);`

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I did not see any quality issues a few years ago when I wrote that sample, but there may be things that I did not anticipate. Ont thing would be to make sure that your output matches the screen resolution -- if something is having to scale the image from the screen to go to your output buffer, that could affect quality.

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right - it is indeed a lower resolution! Maybe you scale the image in the ImageTransmogrifier constructor.

Comment: I have not worked on that code in a few years, and I would need to re-read my own book to remember how that stuff is supposed to work. 

Comment: No worries. You have been of great help! If you want to reply my question with your first comment I will gladly accept it as answer! :)

Comment: While I could post something like that as an answer, technically it would not be a good answer for Stack Overflow, since all it would do would link to outside resources.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have posted a new question. If you want to check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802407/cannot-start-already-started-mediaprojection-and-rarely-nullpointerexception-whe